# Optimize MySQL Intersection Query For Large Data

Tags: mysql, optimization, reporting, bigdata

This is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `instagram_user_followers_mapping` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`instagram_user_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`instagram_profile_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `instagram_unique_user_follower_mapping` (`instagram_user_id`,`instagram_profile_id`),
KEY `instagram_user_followers_mapping_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
KEY `instagram_user_followers_mapping_updated_at_index` (`updated_at`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

I have over 100 Million rows in this table. When I try to fetch common followers between two or more "instagram_user_id", it works fine for profiles who have less than 20,000 rows in the table. But for profiles which have over 2mil rows, it works really slow. And I want to get this data to be displayed realtime for analysis and reporting. The end user might choose any combination of profiles, so creating a summary table is not much of an option here.

The query that I use to fetch the intersection is:

```
select instagram_profile_id, count(*) as myCount 
from instagram_user_followers_mapping 
where instagram_user_id IN ('1142282','346115','663620','985530') 
group by instagram_profile_id HAVING myCount >= 4
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Essentially, everything before `HAVING...` needs to be completely done -- fetching multiple rows from each of 4 ids, sorting, grouping & count.  Only then can the `HAVING` be applied.

Comment: mysql version 5.7.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should run faster, but it would require constructing the query:

```
select  instagram_profile_id
    from  instagram_user_followers_mapping AS t
    WHERE  instagram_user_id = '1142282'
      AND  EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  instagram_user_followers_mapping
            WHERE  instagram_profile_id = t.instagram_profile_id
              AND  instagram_user_id = '346115' 
        )
      AND  EXISTS 
        (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  instagram_user_followers_mapping
            WHERE  instagram_profile_id = t.instagram_profile_id
              AND  instagram_user_id = '663620' 
        )
      AND  EXISTS 
        (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  instagram_user_followers_mapping
            WHERE  instagram_profile_id = t.instagram_profile_id
              AND  instagram_user_id = '985530' 
        );
```

This formulation avoids the filesort and avoids gathering all user_ids for a given profile_id (or vice versa).

Is `innodb_buffer_pool_size` bigger than the index size?

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size is bigger than index.

Answer (score 0):

`IN` clause is a little bit particular. Using this query could solve your problems. I changed `count(*)` to `count(id)` and `IN` statement to equal in where clause.

```
select instagram_profile_id, count(id) as myCount 
from instagram_user_followers_mapping 
where instagram_user_id = '1142282' or instagram_user_id = '346115' or instagram_user_id = '663620' or instagram_user_id = '985530'
group by instagram_profile_id HAVING myCount >= 4
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not change the query time. 

`78763 rows in set (22.95 sec)`

Comment: The semantics of `COUNT(id)` is to count only non-NULL ids.  `COUNT(*)` skips that extra check.  (The answer should be the same in this query.)

Answer (score 0):

The 'IN' vs 'OR' should not be an issue. The query interpreter should consider them to be the same (an EXPLAIN should demonstrate this).

Actually a copy and paste of an EXPLAIN on that query would be very useful...

Since that is a reasonably significant number of rows we are dealing with here and since your indices look sufficient, I would be looking at (2) things. First is overall db config (making sure enough ram to the innodb_buffer_pool, etc). The second (and more likely) problem is the GROUP BY being very slow. Try increasing the sort buffer type parameters, and have a look here for more ideas: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Also, if you can, try running each 'WHERE instagram_user_id =' as a separate query.

In general this is not the sort of thing MySQL does wicked fast but with a bit of work you can probably get it to work for you. You might need to get a bit creative on the application side, depending on how fast you need this to be.